# Jupyter notebook can't find installed modules

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have searched everywhere on stackoverflow, but still can't fix this issue.

I have installed python 3.8 and matplotlib and numpy. The terminal says these modules are already installed. But still these modules can't be found in a Jupyter notebook.

```
pip install matplotlib
pip install numpy
```

All ways of installing give this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.2.2)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.19.5)
```

But when I run a Jupyter notebook and then use these modules:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get the error:

```
<ipython-input-4-a1498ba331d8> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install matplotlib')
      2 
----> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

The same thing happens with other modules

```
import numpy as np
```

Results in

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0ae90a4a98a4> in <module>
----> 1 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

What's going on? Why can't Jupyter find my modules?

Comment: In jupyter find your python executable: `import sys; print(sys.executable)` that is the python environment that your notebook server is running under. That is where you will need to install your packages.

Comment: Thanks! I discovered that Mac OS was stubbornly referencing old homebrew python installs in an obscure `Cellar/Keg` folder, AND there was an old Xcode install in `Libary/CommandLineTools`. I'm still trying to remove everything! At least I know where the error is now.

Comment: That's good and frustrating! You are living this [xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/1987/)! Using your newly installed python3.8 you can [create a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) and [run jupyter and your analyses from there](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/notebook-classic.html#alternative-for-experienced-python-users-installing-jupyter-with-pip)

Comment: Haha yeah that's exactly what's happening :( It just makes me wonder why Python is such a mess? Is nobody in charge over there?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall the modules or close an open the file.

You can also try :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/matplotlib.py')
```

by replacing 'path/matplotlib.py' by the exact path of the module.

Comment: When I reinstall, I get `Requirement already satisfied`. When I quit and reopen Jupyter, I still get `module not found`.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to list the notebook kernel(s) that are installed:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
>>Available kernels:
        %s    %s venv    /Users/username/Library/Jupyter/kernels/venv
        %s    %s python3 /Users/username/Library/Python/3.11/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Next, you can remove all of them with `jupyter kernelspec remove`. In my case I would run

```
jupyter kernelspec remove venv
jupyter kernelspec remove python3
```

Finally, install `ipykernel` with Python 3.8:

```
python3.8 -m ipykernel install --user

>Installed kernelspec python3 in /Users/username/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Now the correct kernel is installed.